# mongodb vs firestore for complex queries

Tags: mongodb, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have to start an application where I need to decide which db should I use

For complex queries which should I prefer mongodb or firestore

Thanks

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing what queries you are needing to perform.  MongoDB is very flexible, but you have to manage the storage / availability / backups / etc.  Cloud Firestore is a managed service and takes away the headache of managing servers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would choose MongoDB but that strongly depends upon which application you want to build.
MongoDB is open source and not Cloud based, it is high portable and supports many programming languages and external products, although query syntax looks a bit more complicated.
If you need auto scaling feature and integration with other Google services then Firestore would be the best choice.

To wrap up, MongoDB seems to be more secure and consistent while Firestore is better suited for mobile apps or application based on real time data.

Comment: For GCP supports MongoDb as a service with auto scaling and so on